# Property 'json' does not exist on type '{}'

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have an abstract base class in Typescript that looks like this:

```
import {Http, Headers, Response} from 'angular2/http'; 
export abstract class SomeService {
    constructor(private http:Http) {}   

    protected post(path:string, data:Object) {
        let stringifiedData = JSON.stringify(data);
        let headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');

        this.http.post(`http://api.example.com/${path}`, stringifiedData, { headers })
            .map(res => res.json())
            .subscribe(obj => console.log(obj));
    }
}
```

It works perfectly. However, the Typescript compiler is complaining about `.map(res => res.json())`. I keep getting this error:

```
ERROR in ./src/app/components/shared/something/some.abstract.service.ts
(13,29): error TS2339: Property 'json' does not exist on type '{}'.
```

I followed the examples in [the angular 2 documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/Http-class.html), and *it works*. I'm just sick of staring at this error. Am I missing something?

Comment: It looks to me like the response you get already is json data, so the json() call is superfluous. And that would make sense since you specify the accept header, where the example link does not.

Comment: @Gimby ah - duh. You are probably right, I can probably drop that line altogether. *But...* the compiler wouldn't know that, right? Shouldn't Typescript still allow me to do this - since it doesn't know what the return data will look like?

Comment: Frankly, I missed the typescript tag myself, I know little to nothing about that :)

Comment: Use `.map((res: Response) => res.json())`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

To me this looks strange...

```
.map(res => (<Response>res).json())
```

I would do

```
.map((res: Response) => res.json())
```

Comment: It's been a while since i wrote this question. I definitely prefer this now as well.

Comment: now since the `Response` class is deprecated, so can you please write this answer also in the context of `HttpResponse` class. Mere replacing won't work, so please!

Comment: "Response" is just a interface.. you can create you own "MyCustomThing" interface and use that.. you would still use it the same way. But keep in mind that the .json() is not needed if you use the newer "HttpClient" instead of "Http"

Comment: I refer to the comment of @Mackelito which is helpful for the newer versions of Angular: `.json()` is not needed when you use "HttpClient" instead of "Http"

Answer (score 9):

You can get rid of this error by type-assertion to `Response`:

```
.map((res: Response) => res.json())
```

`http.post()` will return a `Observable<Response>` on wich `map` will require an Object of type `Response`. I think that's a missing definition in the current TypeScript AngularJS `.d.ts`.

Comment: This may just be a bandaid - but at least the error is gone. Thank you!

Comment: TypeScript thinks `res` is of type empty Object. What type should it be?

Comment: An [observable](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/Observable-class.html) - it's mentioned [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/Http-class.html)

Comment: If it's `Response` you might want to cast it to `<Response>` istead of `<any>`. The problem is, that TypeScript can't automaticly assume res is `Response` because the context in `map` is not specific enough

Comment: `Observable<Response>`?

Comment: So, weird... I really thought you had it with `Observable<Response>` (that looks like it would be more accurate, based on the docs), but actually just plain `Response` is what I needed. If you update your answer I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: OK, I also added some additional Information on why you are facing this Problem.

Comment: I have another Idea: maybe you are missing something on `import` - try `import * from 'angular2/http';`

Comment: prefer `as` syntax for assertion ... also don't call it casting https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/type-assertion.html. Nevertheless +1 

Comment: So `.map(res as Response => res).json())` would work? Sorry for calling it casting

Comment: actually this answer helped me http://stackoverflow.com/a/37725361/942317