# How to return Observable from xhr

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, reactive-programming

I have function like this, it just upload image with xhr request:

```
public uploadAvatar(avatarFile, callback) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let formData: any = new FormData();
      let url = 'avatar';
      let imgArr = "avatar";
      let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

      formData.append(imgArr, avatarFile, avatarFile.name);
      xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
          if (xhr.status == 200) {
            resolve(JSON.parse(xhr.response));
            callback('success');
          } else {
            reject(xhr.response);
            callback('error');
          }
        }
      };

      xhr.open("POST", environment.baseUrl + url, true);
      xhr.setRequestHeader('Auth', this._auth.getToken());
      xhr.send(formData);
    });
  }
```

How can I return Observable insted Promise?

Answer (score 5):

eddyP23's answer is *almost* correct but there are two more things.

One key difference between Observables and Promises is that Observables can be canceled in contrast to Promises. This is very relevant to your situation where you're using XHR to perform AJAX calls. While XMLHttpRequest can be aborted using the [`abort()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/abort) you can't abort pending Promise.

However with Observables you can. When you complete or unsubscribe an Observable you can also cancel the XHR object because you know you're not interested in it.

See also: https://medium.com/@benlesh/promise-cancellation-is-dead-long-live-promise-cancellation-c6601f1f5082

So you function when transformed from using Promises to Observables should look like this:

```
public uploadAvatar(avatarFile, callback) {
    return Rx.Observable.create(function (observer) {
        ...
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
            if (xhr.status == 200) {
                observer.onNext(JSON.parse(xhr.response));
                observer.onCompleted();
            } else {
                observer.onError(xhr.response);
            }
        }

        return () => {
            xhr.abort();
        };
    }
)
```

Notice that we're returning a function which is used when disposing the Observable. For more information about `Observable.create` have a look at http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-create

The second thing is that if you don't care about aborting the XHR you can just use Promises. RxJS 5 treats Promises the same way as Observables. Notice that `Observable.from()` takes as a parameter some `ObservableInput` which is in detail described here: http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/MiscJSDoc.js~ObservableInputDoc.html

For you it means that you can just call `uploadAvatar()` as is and the Promise returned is going to be turned into an Observables automatically:

```
Observable.from(uploadAvatar(...))
    .subscribe(...)
```

Comment: Anyone still looking for a solution in case this does not work for you try the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37750209/4989448)

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work

```
 public uploadAvatar(avatarFile, callback) {
    return Rx.Observable.create(function (observer) {
      let formData: any = new FormData();
      let url = 'avatar';
      let imgArr = "avatar";
      let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

      formData.append(imgArr, avatarFile, avatarFile.name);
      xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
          if (xhr.status == 200) {
            observer.onNext(JSON.parse(xhr.response));
            observer.onCompleted();
            callback('success');
          } else {
            observer.onError(xhr.response);
            callback('error');
          }
        }
      };

      xhr.open("POST", environment.baseUrl + url, true);
      xhr.setRequestHeader('Auth', this._auth.getToken());
      xhr.send(formData);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [fromPromise](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/file/es6/add/observable/fromPromise.js.html) in yours Promise. Remember to import the method before, like

```
import 'rxjs/add/observable/fromPromise';
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple way to do as follow:

```
xhrCall(url, formData, header) {
    return Observable.create(function (observer) {
      let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
          if (xhr.status == 200) {
            observer.next(xhr);
          } else {
            observer.error(xhr);
          }
        }
      };

      xhr.open("POST", url, true);
      xhr.setRequestHeader(header.name, header.value);
      xhr.send(formData);
    });
}
```

Comment: You're missing `observer.complete()` after observer.next(). Or else the observable won't be cleaned up after the request finishes.