# fromPromise does not exist on type Observable

Tags: angular, promise, rxjs, observable, es6-promise

In Angular 2 using rxjs I was trying to convert a Promise to Observable. As many of online guides showed I used `fromPromise` on `Observable`. Which throws error:

```
Property 'fromPromise' does not exist on type 'typeof Observable'.
```

Observable was imported like:

```
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
```

trying to import `fromPromise` like other operators results in error:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/fromPromise';
```

even if I suppress typescript error it still results in error:

```
(<any>Observable).fromPromise
```

Error:

```
Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3_rxjs_Observable__.Observable.fromPromise is not a function
```

Somewhat similar issue was reported on rxjs repo [here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/1507) but there is no solution there either.

Comment: pleas check the version of typescript and rxjs you are using, Observable.fromPromise just should work. check for the file fromPrommis.js in rxjs -> add -> observable -> fromPromise.js

Comment: rxjs 5.4.0 typescript 2.3.4

Comment: and the fromePromise.js does exist

Comment: That explains. Check out the latest version and it should contain that file. If you r on latest then just remove your node modules and do npm i.

Answer (score 215, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

As of `rxjs` 6.0.0-beta.3, operators and observable creators should be imported from `rxjs`. Furthermore, `fromPromise` is not part of the public API anymore and its wrapped in the `from` method.

**TL;DR;**

**UPDATE**

For rxjs 6.0.0 use:

```
import { from } from 'rxjs';

var observableFromPromise =  from(promiseSrc);
```

**UPDATE:**

After the release of the [pipeable operators](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md) in `rxjs` 5.5.x, the monkey patch approach is strongly discouraged. Consider to use the static method option.

**Original answer**

As of `rxjs` 5.4.x, `fromPromise` can be used as a static method or can be patched into the `Observable` prototype.

For the first, you can do the following:

```
import { fromPromise } from 'rxjs/observable/fromPromise';

var observableFromPromise = fromPromise(promiseSrc);
```

More info about this approach [here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/5.4.0/src/observable/fromPromise.ts)

To do the second, you need to change your import statement:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/fromPromise';

var observableFromPromise = Observable.fromPromise(promiseSrc);
```

More info about this approach [here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/5.4.0/src/add/observable/fromPromise.ts)

Personally I would recommend the first one, considering that the 2nd approach is basically the 1rst, with the difference that the `Observable` prototype is changed.

Answer (score 9):

like what Jota said 'from' is the answer.

you can find the reference from here

https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/creation/from.html

However, if you want to specify 'Promise to Observable' 
you could use 'fromPromise' like below.

```
  import { from as fromPromise, Observable} from 'rxjs';
  ...

  private getObservable(): Observable<any> {
    return fromPromise(this.promise);
  }


  private getPromise() {

   this.promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.service.getPromise()
        .then(response => {
          //  do sth
          resolve(response);
        });
    });
}
```