# transform to promise in callback to "from" rxjs6

Tags: angular, angular-promise, rxjs6

[Here](https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/es6-typescript/promises/#_creating_a_promise)

> Inside this inner function we perform our asynchronous processing and
>   then when we are ready we call resolve(), like so:

```
var promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("Async Work Complete");
    resolve();
  }, 1000);
});
```

For concrete code: [here](https://github.com/AngularTemplates/firebase-authentication-with-angular-5/blob/master/src/app/core/user.service.ts) firebase authentication github project,

```
 getCurrentUser(){
    return new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {
      var user = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user){
        if (user) {
          resolve(user);
        } else {
          reject('No user logged in');
        }
      })
    })
  }
```

and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45785513/492258) stated

> For rxjs 6.0.0 use:

```
import { from } from 'rxjs';

var observableFromPromise =  from(promiseSrc);
```

I could imagine solution would be

```
  getCurrentUser() {
    return from(firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function (user) {
      user.getIdToken().then(x => {
        return x;
      })
    })
    )
  }
```

or

```
getCurrentUser() {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function (user) {
      return from(user.getIdToken());
    })

  }
```

My question is what is the equivalent second code snippet to `from` expression in callback?

Comment: I am not sure, if that's just me but I am not able to understand your question. Can you elaborate it further

Comment: Your question is very confusing. Are you confused about the "promiseSrc"? `promiseSrc` is your promise, so you can write a new promise in there if you want to.

Comment: @ShashankVivek Please see last part of what I have tried part, I hope It clarify issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if I totally understand your question but if you are trying to return an observable stream from the user token, maybe the following could work:

```
getCurrentUser(): Observable<any> {
    return new Observable(observer => {
        firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
           user.getIdToken().then(token => {
               observer.next(token);
           }).catch(error => {
               observer.error(error);
           })
        })
    })
}
```

Any time the auth state will change, a new user token will be sent on the stream.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

what about [bindCallback](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/bindCallback):

```
bindCallback(firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged)
  .subscribe(console.log);
```