# Observable from a Promise with nested Promise

Tags: angular, rxjs, xrm

I have a service that call the new Xrm.WebApi endpoint.

This endpoint return a Promise, which have a nested Promise "json" ([documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/model-driven-apps/clientapi/reference/xrm-webapi/online/execute)), which allows to get the json returned by the service.

From this json I extract some data using the "parseData" method, which return it as an Array of objects.

I want to return an `Observable<MyObject[]>`, but all I can get for now is an `Observable<Promise<MyObject[]>>`.

My current code looks like the following :

```js
return from(Xrm.WebApi.online.execute(crmRequest).then(
      result => {
        if (result.ok) {
          return result.json().then(json => {
            let res : MyObject[]= this.parseData(json);
            return res;
          }); 
        }
      },
      error => {
        throw error;
      }
    ));
```

Environment:
- Angular 8.2
- RxJs 6.4

Comment: Take a look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45784825/frompromise-does-not-exist-on-type-observable/45785513), if you have not updated to version 6.x.x you should do it

Comment: If you remove the `from`, is the type returned a `Promise<Promise<MyObject[]>>`?

Comment: @FabianSchmidt I'm already using RxJs 6.4. Add the framework version to my post.
@IraklisGkougkousis It return a `PromiseLike<Promise<MyObject>>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `from` to convert your first Promise to an Observable and use `switchMap` to map to an inner Promise. `filter` is used to only emit results that are ok and `map` is used to map to your desired output. This Observable will error when the first or second Promise errored.

```js
return from(Xrm.WebApi.online.execute(crmRequest)).pipe(
  filter(result => result.ok),
  switchMap(result => result.json()),
  map(json => this.parseData(json) as MyObject[]),
)
```

For more info read my response at: [Convert Promise to Observable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54111045/9423231)

Answer (score 0):

After some tries I got this working with the following code :

```js
return new Observable(observer => {
        Xrm.WebApi.online.execute(crmRequest).then(
          result => {
            if (result.ok) {
              result.json().then(json => {
                let res : MyObject[]= this.parseData(json);
                observer.next(res);
                observer.complete();
              });
            }
          },
          error => {
            observer.error(error);
          }
        );
      });
```

It create an Observable with a custom Observer, and trigger the observer .next() in the nested Promise in order to return the right data.