# Rxjs: are the fromPromise and toPromise operations expensive?

Tags: typescript, rxjs, es6-promise, rxjs6, rxjs-observables

In my TypeScript app I've reached the point where I have a method that internally does several `fromPromise` and `toPromise` operations:

```
  myMethod(...): Promise<string> {
    return fromPromise(this.someService1.someMethod1(...)).pipe(
      mergeMap(param => fromPromise(this.someMethod2(...))),
      map(param => getSomethingFromParam(param)),
    ).toPromise();
  }
```

also the `someMethod1` and `someMethod2` internally use `toPromise` and `fromPromise`.

I understand that if I put it like this, it looks quite messy. However the reason is to have a clean API in every service (e.g. I mostly use the result of `someMethod1` and `someMethod2` as promises so I convert their internal observable to a Promise and expose it like this).

I could of course refactor the whole thing, having my services to expose more methods so I can for example call a method that returns me directly an Observable instead of a Promise.

My question is: do I need such a refactor?

In other words: currently my services' APIs are quite clean, they only expose Promises. But I do have to play with `fromPromise` and `toPromise` whenever I want to benefit from rxjs operators. So I would like to keep things the way they currently are, unless these operations are expensive  (in terms of performance).

Answer (score 1):

First, Your tag mentions **rxjs6**, so `fromPromise` is no longer part of the Global API. Use `from` instead: [fromPromise does not exist on type Observable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45784825/frompromise-does-not-exist-on-type-observable)

Short answer, no it is not expensive.

You are converting it so you can use the power of operators.

Well, `toPromise` was once an operator and now has been merged directly to the **Observable** class.

If we look at the implementation of `toPromise`:

```
toPromise(promiseCtor?: PromiseConstructorLike): Promise<T | undefined> {
promiseCtor = getPromiseCtor(promiseCtor);

return new promiseCtor((resolve, reject) => {
  let value: T | undefined;
  this.subscribe((x: T) => value = x, (err: any) => reject(err), () => 
    resolve(value));
  }) as Promise<T | undefined>;
 }
}
```

We can see that toPromise subscribes to the Observable and get a Promise.

All you are doing is chaining like any other operator so you can innerly subscribe to the observable (like `MergeMap` would do on 10 different Observables for example). Your implementation is legit.