# Angular - TypeError: Cannot read property 'fromPromise' of undefined

Tags: angular, observable, angular-services

I have a problem with TypeError: Cannot read property 'fromPromise' of undefined.

```
Observable.fromPromise(this.myServiceName.myFunctionName(data))
```

It looks like the method in the service is undefined. Problem is that this is only on production. When i do it on local env everything is ok.

Comment: What did you try since now? What are you trying to achieve? We need more code to debug what is happening before that command. Please have a look at the tour from StackOverflow on how to ask question: https://stackoverflow.com/help

Comment: Likely your `import` of `Observable` is incorrect and/or your RxJS dependency does not match.

Comment: Please also check this thread, which answers your question nicely: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45784825/frompromise-does-not-exist-on-type-observable

Comment: Does this answer your question? [fromPromise does not exist on type Observable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45784825/frompromise-does-not-exist-on-type-observable)

Answer (score 0):

Rxjs have a from method to convert promises to observable not fromPromise method. you can find documentation here :-

https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/creation/from